# Write a function to compute the n'th power of a (nxn)matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've added a for to the multiplication of 2 matrices algorithm but it seems it's not working.I need to do this task without using pointers,memory allocation and using only basic instructions(for's,while's,...)

```
void product(double a[][20],double c[][20],int n,int d)
{
    int i, j, k, l;

    for(l = 1;l <= d; ++l) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                c[i][j] = 0;
                for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k]*a[k][j];
                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This function should calculate A^d and store it in c[][20];

Comment: @shekhar suman I wanna' knwo Why my code isn't working and someone to guide me to write the function to calculate a matrix to a power(e.g A^d)

Comment: @Comrade57: Proper English is always appreciated. I wanna' knwo is how we speak in kindergarten.

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry I'm a bit of a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to compute A^(2^d), but instead it calculates A^2 d times.

You can't do a matrix multiplication in place, because as you calculate the result, you would overwrite values. So you need temporary space for one copy (unless d = 0, 1 or 2).

Set C to identity matrix and return if d = 0. Otherwise set C = copy of A, allocate a matrix B, then for l = 1 to d - 1 copy C to B, let C = A * B.. Deallocate B.

Comment: Can you please right code I don't know what you mean by allocate and deallocate of a matrix !

Answer (score 0):

Your code is computing `A^2`, `d` times. You should first initialize C to be the identity matrix, all 0 except on the diagonals where it is 1. Then loop `d` times multiplying `C` by `A`.

Answer (score 0):

For a faster version of this algorithm, multiply powers of 2, using integer math to show the idea of raising a to the nth power:

```
    unsigned int n;   /* unsigned to prevent issues with right shift */
    b = a;            /* a, b, c, t are actually matrices */
    c = 1;            /* identity matrix */
    t;                /* temp matrix */
    while(n){
        if(n&1){      /* if (n&1), c *= b */
            t = c*b;
            c = t;
        }
        t = b*b;      /* b = b^2 */
        b = t;
        n >>= 1;
    }
```